# Validates "presence true" works with edit page but wont work with sign up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is my first question here and im a newbie in rails. I have a weird problem. 
I was following One Month Rails course and I added :name column to DB for user and wanted each new user to have Name while registering and also beign able to change his name while accessing the Edit Page. I added that to devise and wanted to validate so it can't be blank.

The problem is that Edit page works fine (says properly when it's blank and allows for name change) but the Sign Up page ALWAYS says "Name can't be blank" and forbids from creating new user. I have no idea why it is happening, anyone could help?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end


end
```

Here i added Validates in user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :vins, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

This is sign up page:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @validatable %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And edit page:

```
<div class= "panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>
</div>

<div class= "panel-body">
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class= "panel-footer">
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're defining the `configure_permitted_parameters` twice in your `ApplicationController`. So the first definition gets overwritten by the second, and thus the `:name` parameter is not passed to the `sign_in` method through the sanitation. So simply combining the method definition should get rid of the problem.

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end
```

Comment: Oh my God such simple mistake...thank You that worked!

Comment: The simplest mistakes are always the hardest ones to notice on your own.